# How to fix the Xcode path error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, path

In the AFNetworking's [sample code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), I use several folders to classify the source codes.
And the Xcode reports:

> /Users/.../Framework/AFNetworking.h:19:9: 'AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h' file not found
>
> /Users/.../AFNetworking-master/Example/Classes/Networking Extensions/AFAppDotNetAPIClient.h:4:9: While building module 'AFNetworking' imported from /Users/dengjiangzhou/Documents/源码/2_AFNetworking/AFNetworking-master/Example/Classes/Networking Extensions/AFAppDotNetAPIClient.h:4:
>
> /Users/.../AFNetworking-master/Example/:1:9: In file included from :1:

[image]

**And**

[image]

Here is [the code](https://github.com/dengJunior/AFNetworking):
**In the AFNetworking.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//! Project version number for AFNetworking.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double AFNetworkingVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for AFNetworking.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char AFNetworkingVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <AFNetworking/PublicHeader.h>

#import <Availability.h>
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#ifndef _AFNETWORKING_
#define _AFNETWORKING_

#import <AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h>

#if !TARGET_OS_WATCH
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h>
#endif

#import <AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h>
```

Error occurs in the last line.
And I didn't change any code. I just organized the files to check the functions of each module easily.

Maybe insert a file name in the search path of Xcode build settings, is quite OK.
I have not figured it out.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should remove `AFNetworking/` from import line and use

  > `#import ""`

  instead of

  > `#import <>`
- Go to **Build Phases** -> Open **Headers** section -> Move files from **Project** to **Public**.

  [image]

Comment: Something wrong.      **/Users/.../Test/AFNetworking-master/Framework/AFNetworking.h:47:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'AFNetworking':** .  _ </br>_                     **'/Users/.../Test/AFNetworking-master/AFNetworking/session/AFHTTPSessionManager.h'**

Comment: Yes, there is more

Comment: Can you update your question with the code inside `AFNetworking.h` file?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can check again.

Comment: Not OK . I put more details. Hope you can make it. The error we talked about is in **AFNetworking.h**

Comment: You should use `#import "AFNetworking.h"` instead of `@import AFNetworking;`

Comment: Upload the current sample code and add a link to your question

Comment: Updated my answer, you can try again. I tried and it works with your Github project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Select **AFURLRequestSerialization.m**
2. Go to the right tab in the Xcode. Find **Target Membership**. Uncheck and check again all the boxes.
3. **Product > Clean**
4. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and perform: **Product > Clean Build Folder...**
5. Build again.